# How do I make this complex self-joined query with sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js, self-join, sequelize-typescript, nested-includes

I'm trying to build a query in sequelize which basically makes a join between two tables: Resource and ContentTag, which are in a manyToMany relationship:
In sql the query I'd like to obtain whould look like this:

```
`SELECT * FROM Resources-Ctag
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT * FROM Resource-Ctag WHERE ContentTag.keyword="A")as ResourceWithTagA 
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT * FROM Resource-Ctag WHERE ContentTag.keyword="B")as ResourceWithTagB
WHERE  ContentTag.keyword="C"`
```

Where Resources-Ctag is hypotetically the bridge table which associates resources to contentTags.
The objective is to retrieve all resources that contains at least all the three tag together: A, B , C.

Here is the Resource model in sequelize:

```
import { ContentTag } from "./content_tag";

export class Resource extends Model {
  // Default incremental ID
  public id!: number;

  // Model attributes
  public name!: string;

  public description!: string;

  public format!: string;

  public path!: string;

  public metadata!: any;
  public typologyTagId!: string;

  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;

  // Associations

  public addContentTag!: HasManyAddAssociationMixin<ContentTag, number>;
  public getContentTags!: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<ContentTag>;
  public setContentTags!: HasManySetAssociationsMixin<ContentTag, number>;

  public static initialize(sequelize) {
    this.init(
      {
        id: {
          primaryKey: true,
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          unique: false,
        },
        description: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: true,
          unique: false,
        },
        format: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          unique: false,
        },
        path: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          unique: false,
        },
        metadata: {
          type: DataTypes.JSON,
          allowNull: true,
          unique: false,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: true,
        paranoid: true,
        tableName: "resource",
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the ContentTag Model:

```
export class ContentTag extends Model {
  // Default incremental ID
  public id!: string;

  // Model attributes
  public keyword!: string;

  public static initialize(sequelize) {
    this.init(
      {
        id: {
          primaryKey: true,
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },
        keyword: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          unique: false,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: true,
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
        tableName: "content_tag",
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried this but it doesnt work:

```
router.get("/", async (req: any, res: Response) => {
  try {

    const { typologyTag, timeFrom, timeTo, author } = req.query;
    const cTags = JSON.parse(req.query.contentTags)
    const where = {};
    const include = [
      {
        model: TypologyTag,
        as: "typologyTag",
      },
      {
        model: User,
        as: "author",
      },
      {
        model: ContentTag,
        as: "contentTags",
      },
    ];

    if (typologyTag) {
      include[0]["where"] = { keyword: { [Op.eq]: typologyTag } };
    };
    if (author) {
      include[1]["where"] = { displayName: { [Op.eq]: author } };
    };
    if (timeFrom && timeTo) {
      where["createdAt"] = {
        [Op.lt]: timeTo,
        [Op.gt]: new Date(timeFrom)
      };
    } else if (timeFrom) {
      where["createdAt"] = {
        [Op.gt]: new Date(timeFrom)
      };
    } else if (timeTo) {
      where["createdAt"] = {
        [Op.lt]: new Date(timeTo)
      };
    };

   


    if (cTags && cTags.length != 0 && cTags.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator && currentValue,
      true)) {
      include[2]["where"] = { keyword: { [Op.eq]: cTags[0] } };
      if (cTags[1]) {
        include[2]["include"] = [{
          model: Resource,
          as: "resources",
          include: [{
            model: ContentTag,
            as: "contentTags",
            where: { keyword: { [Op.eq]: cTags[1] } },
            include: [{
              model: Resource,
              as: "resources",
              include: [{
                model: ContentTag,
                as: "contentTags",
                where: { keyword: { [Op.eq]: cTags[2] } },
              }]
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }
    };


    const result = await Resource.findAll({
      where: where,
      include: include,
    });
....
```

I made such a huge effort thinking about that solution but now I realise it obviously can't work. Now I have no more clue on how to solve that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix the self-join but also can consider the alternative SQL like this.

Join `ContentTag` where keyword is in "A", "B", "C" to `Resource` and count the keyword per `Resource.id` where the count should be greater than or equal to 3.

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM Resources r 
JOIN (SELECT * 
      FROM ContentTags 
      WHERE keyword IN ('A', 'B', 'C')) c ON r.id = c.resource_id
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.keyword) >= 3;
```

In Sequelize JS (sorry, I don't write TypeScript).

```
Resource.findAll({
  include: {
    attributes: [], // If you need attributes from ContentTag, you need to add aggregation or change to window function.
    model: ContentTag,
    where: {
      keyword: {
        [Op.in]: ['A', 'B', 'C']
      }
    }
  },
  group: ['Resources.id'],
  having: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.literal('DISTINCT keyword')), Op.gte, 3)
})
```